# Array Reduce Error in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Below is the `index.JS` of my firebase database cloud function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database. 
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.update = functions.database.ref('/Player')
    .onWrite(event=>{

   ref = admin.database().ref(`/users/UMFabxncKoZ6XcHpPQYZHizJ7Yr1/week1`);
   pref1 = admin.database().ref("Player").child("playerweek8");
   ref2 = admin.database().ref(`/users/UMFabxncKoZ6XcHpPQYZHizJ7Yr1`);
   if(n === 2){
       ref2.once('value', function(usersSnapshot){
               var users = usersSnapshot.val();
    var selection = users.selection;


    const loadedPlayers = admin.database().ref("Player").child("playerweek8").orderByChild("id");

 var normalizedPlayers = loadedPlayers.reduce(function(acc, next) { acc[next.id] = next; return acc; }, {});
            var selectedPlayers = selection.map(function(num){
                return normalizedPlayers[num];
            }); 
            var players = selectedPlayers;
         var  sum = function(items, prop){
                        return items.reduce( function(a, b){
                        return a + b[prop];
                        }, 0);
                        };
                   var points =   sum(players, 'goals');
                    return ref.set(points); 
});

   }
   else return ref.set(0);

    });
```

The function returns the error message: `TypeError: loadedPlayers.reduce is not a function at /user_code/index`

Is there a way that the reduce and mapping function can work to address this error? Sorry if this question is silly but I am new to Firebase.

Comment: check if the array is not null

Comment: the variable 'loadedPlayers' is a firebase databse node that is not null. I checked

Comment: Check whether loadedPlayers is an array using Array.isArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way `loadedPlayers` stands right now, it's a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#orderByChild) object, because that's what [orderByChild()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#orderByChild) returns.  You haven't actually performed the query to get the data at `Player/playerweek8`.

You'll need to use the [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#once) method on loadedPlayers to actually make the query and get the data.

If you're new to Cloud Functions, I suggest doing a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/) and looking at the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) to find out how it works.